# external jar class not found exception

Tags: android

I m using 2 external jars (**langdetect.jar** and **jsonic-1.2.0.jar)**.

Second one is used inside the first jar. However when i use these jars' class i got the error below. Strangely it works in api level 16 but not working over 21. I dont understand why the classpath error i get regarding to api level...

So far i tried:

- java build path, check the external jars.
- In manifest file removed the name:application_name
- libs folder already libs folder.

any other suggestions?

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.mreinstein-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

[image: class path]

[image: gradle 1]

[image: gradle 2]

Comment: Show your `build.gradle.`

Comment: display ur build.gradle ,and classpath .

Comment: anybody have any idea?

Comment: What exactly is inside the `libs/` folder? Why do you need to edit the classpath for external jar files?

Comment: there are 4 jars inside libs/ folder. The 2 jars i mentioned above,3rd is jsoup jar,4th is android support jar.The 2 jars are not android jars, tjey are java jdk jars. Maybe that can be the reason. But i dont know how to solve the problem. Plus, I suspected dex file method limit, however when i check my dex file. There are only 12000+ methods in my dex file. So that also cannot be a problem.  PS: I m sorry for the other post, since i couldnt get any response, i wanted to get attention . Now i deleted the other post.

Comment: also i get this error while the activity starting at android 5.1.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.widget.WebView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mreinstein-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt resolve it using eclipse so i migrated to Android Studio. Then i added dependencies in the gradle for "org.apache.commons.beanutils.*". Then it worked. 
Probably if i downloaded the library jar to eclipse lib folder, it would be fixed. However since the compilation didnt give any error, i couldnt reck on with it.